# How can I keep my UIAlertView above the keyboard? It will only jump up then return to default

Tags: keyboard, uitextfield, uialertview

I created a uiAlertView that contains textFields for an iPad.  This means that in landscape mode, the alert is covered up by the keyboard.  I searched for a solution and I came up with

```
alert.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(alert.transform, 0.0, 150.0);
```

However, all this seems to do is make the alert "jump" up to 150 and then come back down to its default place.  How can I make the alert stay up high without jumping back down?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the text field's `keyboardAppearance` to `UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert`.

```
aTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
```

There are a few other tricks to putting textfields on UIAlertView.  See [my blog post on the subject](http://zpasternack.blogspot.com/2010/09/uialertview-with-uitextfield.html).